# Android| Basic Auth using retrofit2 and local API

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2, basic-authentication

I started making an app and connected it to a mock API at first. Now I want to connect it an API that runs on my PC.

For starters, I'm trying to implement the login access. Since my API's base URL was http://localhost:5000/energy/api/ I changed it to http://<< MyIPAddress >>:5000/energy/api/ (don't know if this is right yet). I'm testing it on my actual phone. 
But with my code username and password are passed on as parameters, while I'd like to login with basic auth (this is how I do it in Postman).
For example this is how I want the authentication to be done:
[image]

**But with my code I get this:**
[image]

**This is my Request Manager:**

```
object RequestManager {
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()
    init {
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://<<MYIP>>:5000/energy/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
```

**My MainActivity.kt:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        login_button.setOnClickListener {
            buttonClicked()
        }

        if (getTokenFromPrefs()?.length!! > 0) {
            openSearchActivity()
        }
    }

    private fun buttonClicked() {
        val username = username_edittext.text.toString()
        val password = password_edittext.text.toString()
        Log.d("eeee","button clicked " + username_edittext.text.toString() + " password "+password_edittext.text.toString() )

        val call = RequestManager.service.login(username, password)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful ){
                        openSearchActivity()
                        saveTokenToPrefs(response.toString())
                    }else {

                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            }
        })
    }

    val TOKENPREFSKEY = "tokenprefskey"
    private fun saveTokenToPrefs(token: String) {
        val pref = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("CGEEnergy", 0)
        val editor = pref.edit()
        editor.putString(TOKENPREFSKEY, token)
        editor.commit()
    }

    private fun getTokenFromPrefs(): String? {
        val pref = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("CGEEnergy", 0)
        return pref.getString(TOKENPREFSKEY, "")
    }

    private fun openSearchActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        if (getTokenFromPrefs()?.length!! == 0) {
            openMainActivity()
        }
        finish()
    }
    private fun openMainActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

**My API.kt code:** (EDITED AND CORRECTED by user [Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5127363/hello-world) )

```
interface Api {
    @POST("Login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun login(@Field("username") username: String, @Field("password") password: String): Call<LoginResponse>
}
```

**My LoginResponse.java code:**

```
public class LoginResponse {

    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    private String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

}
```

Could someone help me with Basic Auth?
Is there also a problem with my base URL? (added IP instead of localhost).
Any tips would be very appreciated.

PS. for the http security issue, I have already added

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in my **AndroidManifest.xml**

Comment: do a simple test to validate your base url, with your device try to open this IP with a browser

Comment: @FranciscoBarrios if you mean to navigate to http:// myIPaddress:5000/ through chrome for example, I cannot :/

Comment: ok, I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you should see, your pc maybe has an IP like 192.168.0.xxx and your phone (not emulator) should be in the same segment, check the ip of your pc and phone just to sure ;)

Comment: @FranciscoBarrios  I tried running the base url in android's browser but it says site cannot be reached

Comment: Did you add the basic auth header to retrofit API class? You need to add the Authorization Header to the request and add the text: `Basic Base64.encode(<username>:<password>)` For example `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l`

Comment: @PFuster could you please elaborate? Or link me somewhere? I didn't quite understand what I should add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic Auth requires an Authorization header in this format:
`"Basic " + Base64.encode(<username>:<password>)`

You should change your Api interface like this

```
interface Api {
    @POST("Login")
    fun login(@Header("Authorization") authorization: String): Call<LoginResponse>
}
```

Now you can add an Auth header to the call like so:

```
val authPayload = "$userId:$password"
val data = authPayload.toByteArray()
val base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP)

val call = RequestManager.service.login("Basic $base64".trim())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query
```

This annotation use for 'GET' Method.

You need to add `@FormUrlEncoded` before function name for 'POST' Method. And you also need to use `@Field` instead of `@Query` for 'POST' Method. So your method for API Call initerface will become this.

```
@POST("Login")
@FormUrlEncoded
fun login(@Field("username") username: String, @Field("password") password: String): Call<LoginResponse>
```

Comment: This was very helpful! I tried it, but it still won't work (since it still has the authentication issue), but I definitely fixed one problem that I didn't even know existed! Thanks!

Comment: I'd love to but it doesn't solve my authentication problem which was the main issue here :/

Comment: Please try to change your IP to '10.0.2.2'

Comment: I test it on my actual mobile phone so I don't think this is gonna work